# Getting a fatal error when I try to customize theme?

Tags: wordpress

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Exception: Supplied nav_menu_item value missing property: description in D:\laragon\www\woodlea\wp-includes\customize\class-wp-customize-nav-menu-item-setting.php:183

Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/q32uc8

[image: Fatal error message]

Comment: Please share your code, otherwise we can't help out.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can fix it with this code in function.php:

```
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'my_wp_get_nav_menu_items', 10, 3);
function my_wp_get_nav_menu_items($items, $menu, $args) {
    foreach($items as $key => $item)
        $items[$key]->description = '';

    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could figure out how to fix this was to delete my menus and recreate them.